# Django : render a view in other views

Tags: django, django-views

I'd like to "include" a view in all my other views.

Look at my website : www.urlc.be

The "Classement" on the right is displayed on every page but I don't know how to include it the "django style". Right now I'm using AJAX call to display the "Classement" on each page.

Can you help me find a better solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: You solution fine too. If many you users disable js and have problems with browsing you can implement `tags` (as say _arie_), middleware for hardcore djangodevs :). But now you have problems with static. Look at you image paths `/static/media/...` or `/static//`. `static` for css, images for design, `media` for user content and editable content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the table on every page i would use an [`inclusion tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags-inclusion-tags) and include it in the base template that all relevant pages inherit from.

Comment: Indeed inclusion tag seems to be the best solution for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you can take to that.  One is to write some middleware to add some more data to each response as it leaves the view.  The other would be to write your own template tag to render the section in question.  Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs/) for middleware and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/) for template tags.